# Role Scoper plugin -- Page Not visible to public

Tags: wordpress

I made CPT and Custom user for example i made CPT name agent and i make custom user Agent after it i alow specific user fro spcific agent every thing work fine but the problem i get page is not visible to public.
please help me in it. and if deactivate the plugin its work and page visible to public.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/

Comment: Did you try to contact your plugin's support forum first ? There are so many plugins you would be lucky to find someone who knows the one you're talking about here...

Comment: yes i did no replay here is my question https://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-not-visible-to-public?replies=1#post-8362429

Comment: Well, plugins author are not always on their forum, you may have to wait more than 2 hours... If you want help here, you have to give a LOT more details, since we don't know how the plugin works. We may only help you to debug...